# Как удалить портал Битрикс24 с пользователем-администратором?

Tags: php, 1с, интерфейс, битрикс24, удаление

Есть портал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуется его удалить. Загуглил [как удалить портал битрикс24](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%8124&oq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqDAgBEAAYFBiHAhiABDIGCAAQRRg5MgwIARAAGBQYhwIYgAQyBwgCEAAYgAQyCAgDEAAYFhgeMggIBBAAGBYYHjIKCAUQABgPGBYYHjIICAYQABgWGB4yCAgHEAAYFhgeMggICBAAGBYYHjIICAkQABgWGB7SAQoxMDI5MGoxajE1qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). В 1-м результате ([Как удалить аккаунт в Битрикс 24](https://uchet-jkh.ru/i/kak-udalit-akkaunt-v-bitriks-24/#:%7E:text=%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81,%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83%20%C2%AB%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82%C2%BB.)) написано, что надо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть главное окно портала

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где в нем можно найти **Настройки аккаунта**? Как выполнить вышеперечисленную последовательность действий (приведите скриншоты)?

При щелчке на иконку пользователя

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

открывается окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где в нем можно удалить портал, я не знаю. Прошу не минусовать, т.к. я новичок в настройке Битрикс24.

**P.S. Мне нужно задействовать этот аккаунт на другом портале Битрикс24**.

Comment: Просто интересно, а через поддержку нельзя это сделать?

Comment: @pyduti поддержка платная, такого вопроса среди имеющихся нет.

Answer (score 1):

Если облачная версия:
Если в течение **50 дней никто из пользователей не зайдет в Битрикс24** c тарифом «Бесплатный», то такой портал считается неактивным и будет автоматически удален. Восстановить удаленный Битрикс24 будет нельзя.
[читать тут](https://helpdesk.bitrix24.ru/open/1332261/)
Если коробочная: просто удалите с хостинга

Comment: Я не хочу ждать 50 дней. Я скачал битрикс24 с bitrix24.ru/features/desktop.php. Что необходимо сделать, чтобы удалить портал? **Мне нужно задействовать этот аккаунт на другом портале Битрикс24.** Каким образом можно это сделать?

Comment: @vladdv вы можете задействовать один и тот же аккаунт на сколько угодно порталов. лишь бы вас пригласили туда или вы сами его создали.